# Hibernate ignore property under some circumstances

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a domain object that contains another domain object; call them A and B.  B contains a blob (an image file) which can be large.  As long as I am only dealing with one A at a time having B on A isn't a concern.  However, sometimes I'll be dealing with thousands of A in which carrying around the blob on B causes heap to run out.  When I am dealing with so many A I really don't need B anyway.

Is there some way of telling Hibernate to ignore this property for a particular call?  Should I just make B transient and deal with updating/deleting manually in this case?

Right now to get around this problem I use a SQL query to pull all the ids I want then iterate over that list getting each domain object out, doing what I need, then evicting it.

Also, I can't lazy load B because I'm in a servlet environment so my Hibernate session is closed before I access the properties in most cases.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {

  private Long id

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id", nullable = true)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private B b

  ...getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {
  private Long id;
  private byte[] blob;

  ...getters and setters
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some way of telling Hibernate to ignore this property for a particular call? Should I just make B transient and deal with updating/deleting manually in this case?

One option would be to use lazy property fetching (this requires bytecode instrumentation, refer to the documentation). So you could map B like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Lob
  private byte[] blob;

  // getters and setters
}
```

And, as documented:

> You can force the usual eager fetching of properties using `fetch all properties` in HQL.

Another option would be to use an alternative version of A (A') without the B, for this special use case.

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.2.2. Mapping simple properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property)
- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [20.1.8. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  Setting as a lazy load for most situations and then adding the fetch all properties in just the queries I need the Lob did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Will the [select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select) of HQL help? With the appropriate constructor added to `A`, you can have the HQL return a collection of `A`s with all properties expect `b` loaded. If I remember correctly, the Hibernate `Session` does not track such partial objects, so updates made to the object wont be flushed to the DB. But in your case, since you close to `Session` anyway, it might not matter.

Comment: I ended up using this mechanism on another part of the code.  Thanks for the contribution.